# What's the difference between on-axis and peak intensity for a Gaussian beam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I am asked to find the ratio of the on axis intensity at z=zR (Rayleigh range) to the peak intensity, given that the Gaussian beam solution is:

ε(ρ,z) = ε0 (ω0 / ω) exp(ikρ^2 / 2R) exp(-ρ^2 / ω^2)

Attempt at solution:

I know intensity is the modulus squared of ε(ρ,z), giving

I = ε0^2 (ω0 / ω)^2 exp(-2ρ^2 / ω^2)

And hence I(zR) = 0.5ε0^2 exp(-ρ^2 / ω^2)

But where is the peak intensity calculated? Is it calculated at z=0 (and hence ω = ω0?) 
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The answer to the question is 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the peak intensity is at $z=0$. By the way, you should have written how $\omega$ and $z$ are related.

Comment: Do you mean ω^2 = ω0^2 (1 + (z/zR)^2)? (i.e. giving ω(zR) = 2^0.5 * ω0). I still do not fully understand how to get 0.5 as the answer - because I get  a factor exp(-ρ^2 / ω0^2) in the formula for intensity at zR, but a factor exp(-2ρ^2 / ω0^2) in the formula for intensity at z=0 - which do not cancel?

Comment: @emc3636: That's right. You should put $\rho=0$, as you need "the ratio of the on axis intensity". And don't forget the  $\omega 0/\omega$ factor.